# premake5 using MS compiler with gmake

Tags: premake

I want to use premake with MS compiler but with (gmake) makefiles.
I tried toolset ("msc") but the generated make file tries to call g++.
Does premake not allow msc in combination with gmake ?

Answer (score 0):

Premake is using your environment's `$CC` and `$CXX` variables. If you want to use MSC, you will also need to set those variables to the appropriate paths.